# Let $S=\{a,b\}$. Which binary operation $*$ on $\wp(S)$ makes $(\wp(S),*)$ a cyclic group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-set-theory, finite-groups, boolean-algebra

Let $S=\{a,b\}$ be a set, and $\wp(S)$ the power set of $S$. It is well known that $$(\wp(S),\triangle,\emptyset)\cong \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2\,,$$ where $\triangle$ is the symmetric difference of two sets.

Now, there are $24$ bijections $f\colon \mathbb{Z}_4 \to \wp(S)$, and hence as many operations "$*$" in $\wp(S)$ such that $$(\wp(S),*,f(0))\cong \mathbb{Z}_4.$$ I tried by trial and error several times, but I couldn't succeed in finding any of such operations *as a symmetric (being the group abelian), closed formula in terms of the basic set operations $\cup, \cap,\setminus$*, just like the symmetric difference formula.

Comment: You can just make an assignment $f:\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\to \mathcal{P}(S)$ by sending, for example, $0\mapsto \emptyset$, $1\mapsto \{a\}$, $2\mapsto \{a,b\}$, and $3\mapsto \{b\}$.  Then, for $A,B\in\mathcal{P}(S)$, define $A*B$ to be  $$f\big(f^{-1}(A)+f^{-1}(B)\big)\,.$$

Comment: I know that, but can you express your $*$ with a closed formula using set union, intersection, difference?

Comment: It is unclear why you think such an operation *should* exist.

Comment: @user1729, I assumed the existence to be settled by the argument recalled by Batominowski. If you mean that none of the operations gotten via those 24 bijections can be given a closed formula in terms of the basic set operations, well this would be a fortiori the answer to my question.

Comment: I made a question that generalizes your problem.  I hope somebody finds an answer.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3754768/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $(B,+,\cdot)$ be the Boolean algebra with two generators $u$ and $v$.  The multiplication in $B$ is given by $u\cdot u=u$, $v\cdot v=v$, and $u\cdot v=v\cdot u=0$.  Therefore, $e:=u+v$ is the multiplicative identity of $B$.

We identify $0$, $u$, $v$, and $e$ with $\emptyset$, $\{a\}$, $\{b\}$, and $\{a,b\}$, respectively.  Then, we can associate any set operation on $\mathcal{P}(S)$ with a polynomial operator in $B$.  This is because the symmetric difference operator $\triangle$ is associated to the polynomial $d(x,y):=x+y$, the union operator $\cup$ is associated to the polynomial $f(x,y):=x+y+x\cdot y$, the intersection operator $\cap$ is associated to the polynomial $g(x,y):=x\cdot y$, the set difference operator $\setminus$ is associated to $h(x,y):=x+x\cdot y$, and the  complement operator is associate to the polynomial $k(x):=e+x$.

Suppose that there exists a polynomial $p(x,y)\in B[x,y]$ such that the binary operation on $\mathcal{P}(S)$ equips $\mathcal{P}(S)$ with a structure of $G:=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$.  Let $z\in B$ be the element that acts as the identity of $G$.  Since $G$ is abelian, we get $p(x,y)=p(y,x)$, whence
$$p(x,y)=\alpha+\beta\cdot x+\beta\cdot y+\gamma\cdot x\cdot y$$
for some $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in B$.    Now,
$$0=p(0,z)=\alpha+\beta\cdot z\,.$$
Therefore,
$$\beta\cdot z=\alpha\,.$$
We also have
$$z=p(z,z)=\alpha+\beta\cdot z+\beta\cdot z+\gamma\cdot z\cdot z=\alpha+\gamma\cdot z\,.$$
Hence,
$$(e+\gamma)\cdot z=z+\gamma\cdot z=\alpha\,.$$
Furthermore,
$$\begin{align}e=p(e,z)&=\alpha+\beta\cdot e+\beta\cdot z+\gamma\cdot e\cdot z
\\&=\alpha+\beta+\alpha+(\alpha+z)=\alpha+\beta+z\,.\end{align}$$
Consequently,
$$z=e+\alpha+\beta\,.$$
From $\beta\cdot z=\alpha$, we conclude that $\alpha\cdot\beta=\alpha$, or $$\alpha\cdot(e+\beta)=0\,.$$

**Case I:** $\beta=0$.  Then, $\alpha=\beta\cdot z=0$.  Therefore, $z=e+\alpha+\beta=e$.  As $(e+\gamma)\cdot z=\alpha$, we conclude that $\gamma=e$.  Hence, $p(x,y)=x\cdot y$, which clearly does not work.  (Alternatively, note that $p(0,0)=0$, which contradicts the result that $z=e$ is the identity of $G$.)

**Case II:** $\beta=u$.  Then, $\alpha\cdot v=\alpha\cdot(e+\beta)=0$.  Hence, either $\alpha=0$ or $\alpha=u$.

- If $\alpha=0$, then from $z=e+\alpha+\beta$, we get $z=v$.  From $(e+\gamma)\cdot z=\alpha$, we conclude that $\gamma=0$ or $\gamma=v$.  In the case $\gamma=0$, we get $p(x,y)=u\cdot(x+y)$, which means that the image of $p(x,y)$ can only be $0$ or $u$, leading to a contradiction.  In the case $\gamma=v$, we get $$p(x,y)=u\cdot(x+y)+v\cdot(x\cdot y)\,,$$
  whence
  $$p(u,0)=u\cdot(u+0)+v\cdot(u\cdot 0)=u\,,$$
  but this contradicts the conclusion that $z=v$ is associated to the identity of $G$.
- If $\alpha=u$, then $z=e+\alpha+\beta=e$.  From $(e+\gamma)\cdot z=\alpha$, we conclude that $\gamma=v$.  Ergo,
  $$p(x,y)=u+u\cdot(x+y)+v\cdot(x\cdot y)\,.$$
  Thus,
  $$p(u,u)=u+u\cdot(u+u)+v\cdot(u\cdot u)=u\,.$$
  This contradicts the result that $z=e$ is associated to the identity of $G$.

**Case III:** $\beta=v$.  The argument is the same as Case II.

**Case IV:** $\beta=e$.  Then, $z=e+\alpha+\beta=\alpha$, and from $(e+\gamma)\cdot z=\alpha$, we get $\gamma\cdot\alpha=0$.

- If $\alpha=0$, then $z=0$ and $$p(x,y)=(x+y)+\gamma\cdot(x\cdot y)\,.$$
  Therefore, $p(\gamma,\gamma)=\gamma$ implies that $\gamma$ is associated to the identity of $G$, making $\gamma=z=0$.  Thus, $p(x,y)=x+y$, which clearly does not work.  (Alternatively, note that $p(0,0)=0$, which contradicts the result that $z=e$ is the identity of $G$.)
- If $\alpha=u$, then $z=u$ and $$p(x,y)=u+(x+y)+\gamma\cdot(x\cdot y)\,.$$  Note that $\gamma\cdot \alpha=0$ implies $\gamma=0$ or $\gamma=v$.  If $\gamma=0$, then $p(0,0)=u=p(v,v)$, which contradicts the fact that $G$ has only one element of order $2$.  If $\gamma=v$, then $p(e,v)=v$, which contradicts the result that $u$ is associated to the identity of $G$.
- If $\alpha=v$, then we have a similar contradiction to the previous subcase.
- If $\alpha=e$, then $z=e$ and $\gamma=0$, making $$p(x,y)=e+(x+y)\,.$$  Now, $p(x,x)=e$ for all $x\in B$ contradicts the fact that $G$ has only one element of order $2$.

Therefore, such a polynomial $p(x,y)\in B[x,y]$ does not exist.  Hence, there is no binary operator $*$ on $\mathcal{P}(S)$ given by the usual set operations that makes $\mathcal{P}(S)$ isomorphic to the group $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$.

**P.S.**  See a much simpler argument to a more generalized setting [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3754768/).