# let $|S| = 3$. Prove $(P(S),\Delta)$ is not isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z_8},+)$.

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory, group-isomorphism

Hi everyone I hope somone can help
I have some set $S$ with $3$ elements $P(S)$ is the power set.I need to prove that $(P(S),\Delta)$ is not isomorphic to  $(\mathbb{Z_8},+)$. I tried building a function to show that associativity doesn't work with no success .
any idea ?
Thank you very much

Comment: Associativity won't work as a differentiator; both are commutative groups, so you'll need to be a lot more narrow in your checking. Broad hint: can you think of some property that all elements of $(P(S),\Delta)$ satisfy that some elements in $C_8$ don't?

Comment: You know that $A\Delta B=0$ for all $A$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe or even $A\Delta A=\emptyset$.

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3754768/can-we-equip-the-power-set-p-of-any-set-s-with-a-binary-operation-such-that.

Comment: @Mohsen This is not a duplicate of that question. Here the operation is given (symmetric difference) while there they are asking a much more general question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(\mathbb Z_8,+)=C_8$ is cyclic. If it would be isomorphic to $(\mathcal P(S), \Delta)$, $(\mathcal P(S), \Delta)$ would be generated by a unique element. That can’t be as $A \Delta A= \emptyset$ for all $A \in \mathcal P(S)$.